# Java: Copy Constructor not going as planned

Tags: java, constructor, copy, copy-constructor

I have a bit of a problem. I'm making a Finite Automata checker. 
Given an input, and the DFA, does it end on a accepting state.

My problem is creating a new DFA_State from another's target.

```
DFA_State state0, state1, curr_state, init_state, temp; //fine, I think
state0 = new DFA_State();
state1 = new DFA_State();
state0 = new DFA_State("State 0",true, state0, state1); //fine, I think
init_state = new DFA_State(state0);  //fine, I think
```

but, this bit is throwing up problems.

```
temp = new DFA_State(curr_state.nextState(arr1[i]));
*
*
curr_state = new DFA_State(temp);
```

Thanks for any help,
Dave

Edit:
God I was retarded when I did this, AFAIK, I just wasn't thinking straight, added methods to set the values to the DFA_State object.

```
//in DFA_State class
public void set(DFA_State on_0, DFA_State on_1, Boolean is_accepting, String name){
    this.on_0 = on_0;
    this.on_1 = on_1;
    this.is_accepting = is_accepting;
    this.name = name;
}
//in main
DFA_State state0, state1, curr_state; 
state0 = new DFA_State();
state1 = new DFA_State();
state0.set(state0, state1, false, "State 0");
state1.set(state1, state0, true, "State 1");

curr_state = state0;//initial state
//iterate across string input changing curr_state depending on char c
curr_state = getNextState(c);
//at end
if(curr_state.isAccepting()) 
    System.out.println("Valid, " + curr_state.getName() + " is accepting);
else 
    System.out.println("Invalid, " + curr_state.getName() + " is not accepting);
```

Comment: This looks like homework; please state that in the question. Also, can you be more specific about what "throwing up problems" means? (is there a stack trace, etc?)

Comment: yes it's homework, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Exception?  If so post the exception stacktrace.  Typically in Java if we want to create a copy constructor we'll just override clone() method, and implement Cloneable.  You can certainly create a copy constructor if you want, but clone() works just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that first line, you declare the variables `state0`, `state1`, `curr_state`, `init_state` and `temp` as being variables of type `DFA_State`. However, that only declares them, they are not yet initialized. The next few lines are all okay. Second line creates a state without anything in it and assigns it to `state0`, so does the third line for `state1`. Fourth line overwrites your previous `state0` assignment with a new `DFA_State` that has actual contents. Fifth line creates a `DFA_State` as a copy of `state0` and assigns it to `init_state`.

Assuming there's nothing in between this and the first line of your second code block, now you'll get a problem. You're assigning `temp` with a new `DFA_State` that uses a copy-constructor with an argument relying on `curr_state`. But at that point, that variable hasn't been initialized yet. Just because it was declared doesn't mean it has somehow already been structured in memory. When you call `nextState` on it, there's simply no variable to resolve this to. Don't expect to get something like a pointer that will eventually point to a part of what you put in `curr_state`.

I'm just guessing, but from your code style I'd say you have a background in C or C++. Look into the differences between those languages and Java. If possible, I'd also advise you to make your `DFA_State` class immutable, since this is more reliable and will avoid mistakes. That means getting rid of the no-args constructor. Here's a reworking of it (not actually compiled, might contain errors):

```
package foundations.of.computing;

/**
 *
 * @author Kayotic
 */
class DFA_State {
    private final String state;
    private final DFA_State on_0;
    private final DFA_State on_1;
    private final boolean isAccepting;
    //private DFA_State dummy;

    public DFA_State(DFA_State arg) {
        //this(arg.is_accepting(), arg.on0(), arg.on1());
        state = arg.get_name();
        isAccepting = arg.is_accepting();
        on_0 = arg.on0();
        on_1 = arg.on1();
    }

    public DFA_State(String name, Boolean accepting, DFA_State on0, DFA_State on1) {
        state = name;
        isAccepting = accepting;
        on_0 = on0;
        on_1 = on1;
    }

    public String get_name(){
        return state;
    }


    public Boolean is_accepting() {
        return isAccepting;
    }

    public DFA_State on0() {
        return on_0;
    }

    public DFA_State on1() {
        return on_1;
    }

    public DFA_State nextState(char i) {
        if (i == '0') {
            return on0();
        } else if (i == '1') {
            return on1();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error with input");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Even if you can't make the instance variables final, it's best to at least make them private, since you already have methods for getting them.

Comment: I need the no args constructor to initialize my DFA_States
`code`
    state0 = new DFA_State();
    state1 = new DFA_State();
    state0 = new DFA_State("State 0",true, state0, state1); //state0 and state1 need to have been initialized
`code`

Answer (score 0):

There are better memory representations of DFAs than the object-oriented.

You should use a simple lookuptable:

```
int[] table = new int[vocabularyCount][stateCount];
```

Every State and every word gets a number, starting with 0.
Fill the table with the state transitions, or -1, if there is no transition. Now you just need the translation methods for the states and the words.

Heres a generic DFA algorithm:

```
public boolean checkSentence(String s, int[] finishes) {
    // fill table

    int state = 0; // assuming S0 is the start state
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        state = table[translate(s.charAt(i))][s];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < finishes.length; i++) {
        if (finishes[i] == state) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for focusing on the problem domain. Object-orientation might work well, though. But maybe this approach will be clearer to the OP.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OOP for designing DFAs.  In fact it actually is a tighter representation with more expressiveness than an Edge Table data structure in some cases.  Some algorithms work better with ET and some work better with a linked structures like this example. The state pattern in the patterns book talks about using a state just as this question shows so it's quite reasonable to use this representation.  Suggesting he switch to an ET doesn't make his problem magically go away.

Comment: This is just a working implementation, showing a simple solution for the DFA problem. Because the OP neither gave a clear description of his problem, nor posted his full source code, this is a valid solution for showing him the principle.

Answer (score 0):

The program is quite poorly written. Look at this in your FoundationsOfComputing.java:

```
    state0 = new DFA_State();
    state1 = new DFA_State();

    state0 = new DFA_State("State 0",true, state0, state1);
```

You essentially created 3 instances of state - two instances which are not initialized (first two lines in your code) - all their instance variables are null.

Then you create the third instance, which you point to the first two uninitialized ones, and assign it to state0 variable. Please note, at this point, it is only the value of the variable that changes, not the values you passed in the DFA-State constructor!!! So, what you now have in state0 is a state that points to two uninitialized states.

Now let's look at the code further down in the FoundationsOfComputing.java:

```
    while (i < arr1.length) {//loops through array
        System.out.println(i + ". scan shows " + arr1[i]);
        temp = new DFA_State(curr_state.nextState(arr1[i]));
        System.out.println("   "+curr_state.get_name()+ " moves onto " + temp.get_name());
        curr_state = new DFA_State(temp);
        i++;
    }
```

I am guessing this throws NullPointerException - that code moves to the on_0 state of state0 - which is a state that has not been initialized (all it's instance variables are null), so in the following pass of the loop, when it calls curr_state.nextState(whatever), it would return null and you are trying to pass that to the copy-constructor which would result in NPE.

Comment: I've never declared something that taken itself as an argument. It appears I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we know this is homework.  Let's do this instead of telling you the answer let's try and work through it on your own.  If you are seeing a NullPointerException (NPE).  Grab the second line of the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
   at com.blah.blah.SomeObject.someMethod(SomeArgumentType):1234 <<< here
   ....
```

That 1234 is the line number in the file that contains SomeObject.  If you goto that line number you can see exactly where the NPE is being generated from.  For example if line 1234 was:

```
this.foo = bar.indexOf("caramel");
```

You can easily deduce what was null.  No clue?  Well *this* can never be null so *this.foo* isn't the problem.  If *this* could be null you couldn't be inside that method because *this* points to the instance you are currently within.  Therefore, the only other statement where a variable is being dereferenced is bar so *bar* must be null.  Let's look at your code:

```
temp = new DFA_State(curr_state.nextState(arr1[i]));
```

Say you find out the line above is tossing an exception.  Well there could be several things that could be null.  curr_state could be null, or arr1 could be null in which case this line would blow up.  However, if arr1[i] is null or curr_state.nextState() is returning null then you won't see the NPE pointing at this line, but would be coming out of the constructor should someone try to call methods on that method parameter.

Hopefully, this will give you the tools you need to track down problems in your application by understanding exception stack traces.